# Highcharts in cakephp

Tags: highcharts, cakephp-2.3

i am very newby in cakephp, can anyone tell me step by step working with highcharts in cakephp. and also how to show my data from my database.

Here is my database columns(total 11)

CALL TIME,BILL DURATION,FIRST_CELL_ID,LAST_CELL_ID,CALL DIRECTION,ESN_or_IMEI_NO,MIN_or_IMSI_NO 
TYPE OF CONNECTION,SMS CENTRE,ROAMING DETAILS,BTS_ADDRESS

please help me....thanks in advanced

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at this  here [CakePHP Highcharts plugin](https://github.com/destinydriven/cakephp-highcharts-plugin). Do note however that this is specifically for CakePHP 2.* version and will not work with previous versions.

It includes example code for its usage and has been tested with CakePHP 2.5.7.